# How to revive / resubmit stuck SGE jobs ( Usage of qsub? )

Tags: amazon-web-services, hpc, sungridengine, spot-instances

I am trying to revive/resubmit stuck jobs (which run on an SGE scheduler) due to a node crash or say AWS spot instances being taken away? Can someone help in resuming such jobs? I have been trying to understand the usage of **`qsub`** but not able to configure something that will automatically resubmit such jobs.

Also unable to configure my queue using **`qconf`** command as only *`root`* & *`sge_admin`* users can run this command, I do have *`root`*-privileges but asks me to set the **`SGE_ROOT`** environment variable, which I did but still keeps throwing the error to set the variable.

Any sort of assistance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the qsub man page:

```
  -r y[es]|n[o]
       Available for qsub and qalter only.

       Identifies the ability of a job to be rerun or not.  
       If the value of -r is 'yes', the job will be rerun if the job was 
       aborted without leaving a consistent  exit state.  

       (This is typically the case if the node on which the job is running
       crashes).  If -r is 'no', the job will not be rerun under any circumstances.
       Interactive jobs submitted with qsh, qrsh or qlogin are not rerunnable.

       Qalter allows changing this option even while the job executes.
```

So adding

```
#$ -r y
```

in your job script should cater for this.